# The best option to Assigning a public IP to VM

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, kvm

I have a CentoS 7 server with one Interface. I have installed a Linux VM on this using KVM/QEMU and it is working fine with NAT configuration. Now, what I want to do is to **assign a separate public IP** (I have) to this VM so that It can be publicly accessed for web site and ssh access. I want to make sure that Host server is access normally as before VM creation but VM should be accessed separately from remote.

I have **tried to use bridge option on Host** from various online guides e.g., [Link 1](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-bridged-networking-with-libvirt-and-kvm) but what it did, it remove my Host system remote access when I this interface as master to bridge.

Where I am wrong and what could be the best option to do this job

Comment: If this is a server hosted by a host provider, each host provider documents a method and restrictions (eg: MAC address restrictions) on how to do this. You have to check this documentation or else at least provide a link to this documentation in the question.

Comment: And also, as you saw, it's almost impossible to not lose network access during reconfiguration: you need a remote *console* access to test configuring this (without committing it to permanent configuration which could lose access after a reboot).